# Works on Simulator, fails on device: error: WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I am seeing the following error when trying to run a project on a real device, in the simulator it runs fine.

`error: WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions. Verify that the value of NSExtensionPointIdentifier in your WatchKit Extension's Info.plist is set to com.apple.watchkit`

### Things which may or may not be relevant

- I am using cocoa pods in both the watch and main app target
- The project is mostly objective-c but has a few swift files
- Xcode 8.1 (8B62)
- Device Software Versions: iOS 10.1.1 & WatchOS 3.1
- Deployment Info > Deployment Target: iOS 10.0 watchOS 3.0

### Things I’ve tried

- I have checked several times that all the correct files belong to the watch target. I may have missed something here, but I assume it wouldn’t run on the simulator if this was the case
- Bundle identifiers

  - main app’s identifier: `< app id >`
  - watch app’s bundle identifier: `< app id >.watchkit`
  - watch app’s `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier`: `< app id >`
  - watch extension’s bundle identifier: `< app id >.watchkit.extension`
  - watch extension’s `NSExtension`>`NSExtensionAttributes`>`WKAppBundleIdentifier`: `< app id >.watchkit`
- `NSExtension`>`NSExtensionPointIdentifier`: `com.apple.watchkit`
- `WKWatchKitApp` is set to `YES` in both the Watch Extension and the Watch App
- I have removed and re-added the .appex from `Build Phases`>`Embed App Extensions`
- Ensuring `Mach-O Type` is set to `executable` in all targets
- Re-installing pods as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907696/1343140)
- Clearing derived data
- Clearing build folder
- Restarting Xcode
- I tried an archive and this failed with the same error

In lieu of an answer, advice on debugging / troubleshooting this would be appreciated too.

Comment: Apple Developer Technical Support Pointed me to Technical Note TN2424: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2424/_index.html Although this didn't help me, it may help others. I will update with a solution when I have one

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this intermittently, but usually rebuilding a second time fixed it. I've never got to the bottom of why.

I've always assumed it's a bug in Xcode.

Sorry can't be more help, but you're not alone in seeing this.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried building twice just in case, no joy tho :( I'm sure this is something simple, I just wish the error gave more direction.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error, with 3 other errors.

Turned out the problem is that `Valid Architectures` is set incorrectly. Under Build Settings, make sure `Valid Architectures` includes `i386` and `armv7k`.

Once that is fixed, the watch extension will be build, and all errors gone.